# Free geocoding service with non-restrictive license

Tags: geocoding, bing-maps

I am looking for a geocoding service where I can make a request with an address or intersection, not necessarily separated into separate fields (street, city, state, etc.) and get the latitude and longitude, along with suggestions and corrections for misspelled or ambiguous queries.

I really like the Google Geocoding API, but the terms of use say that I am not allowed to store the responses or use the service for any purpose other than showing the result on one of their maps. I am planning to use it for a lightweight, mobile-friendly website that may have the option of displaying results with text only, so this would not work, assuming I am interpreting their terms correctly.

The Yahoo PlaceFinder API looks nice but it comes with similar restrictions.

I am trying to decide what would be a good choice. The Bing API looks good. I don't see any sort of restriction in their terms but am I missing something?

Does anyone know what would be a good choice? I have very limited funding, so I would prefer something that is free or cheap, at least for the near future.

Comment: I have a feeling that what I am asking for is too good to be true but I thought it would be at least worth a try to ask about it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to use Google's API without the restriction, and without violating their license? If so, how much would it cost?

Comment: You'd have to call up google on that one.  They don't seem publish that kind of information.  They'll probably want some percentage of the revenue from the application.

Comment: Haha. If my application doesn't make any revenue, does that mean I don't have to pay them? Or is it not that simple?

Comment: I can't speak for google but you never know.  They might consider it a potential revenue source so will invest.

Comment: Bing does have similar restrictions, I checked about 18 months ago.  I can't speak to any of them, but checkout the list at https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/Geocode/About/GeocoderList.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), it's a tool to search [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data by name and address.

[MapQuest provide a free API](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/) as long as you give the [appropriate credit](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim)

I'm not sure how well it handles misspellings or ambiguous queries though!

Comment: One of the main problems with Nominatim is the lack of house numbers. If you can live without these then Nominatim is probably the best (only?) free solution.